# QTableView float precision

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtableview

Turns out `QTableView` is truncating my floats. For example I have value `0.258` and upon editing it will be turned to `0.26`. Is it possible to make `QTableView` support more than two decimal digits after floating point?

Comment: Can you add some sample code?  I'm not seeing the same problem.

Comment: If i do understand you correctly and assuming that you are using the
    "QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const"
function by returning floats directly
    "return myfloat;"
You might end up want to use: something like that:
    "return QString("%1").arg(myfloat,0,'f', 3);"

Comment: I see the same problem. When you return a float directly you even get spinners and can only edit two decimal places by default. There might be another solution keeping the spinners if one goes into the depths of how different types of content are processed and displayed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... I think the TableView is providing a spin box as the default delegate for editing the float values and the default spinner settings only have 2 decimal places of precision... maybe a custom Delegate would solve it?